# How to achieve slide in and slide out animation with pushing exit activity in back?

Tags: android

So far i have achieve smothly slide in and slide out animation like view pager has, but i want one animation like facebook has when you go to profile and exit activity doesn't go completely left. It pushes activity behind, i don't know how to explain that, but if you have facebook application, you will know what i'm talking about. This is my xml files:

**slide in left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide out left**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()`. And inside that just override the animation like this:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
```

Comment: I'm asking for animation how to achieve. I know how to implement this animation.